# Dynamicly set document root for subdomains using regex

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

I've setup subdomain wildcard to accept anything subdomian,the main problem is that i use DirectAdmin and i am not able to point subdomain to specific path using DA API
i want to point any subdomian to a folder named as subdomian which is exist in subdirectory

for example sub.domian.com should point to /public_html/subdomains/sub

something like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot /public_html/subdomains/%1
</VirtualHost>
```

this would be my ideal if i set subdomains which content a word like ".x" to point in that path

maybe like

```
<VirtualHost *.x:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot /public_html/subdomains/%1
</VirtualHost>
```

sorry if question sounds stupid

Answer (score -3, accepted):

found the answer

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www\.domain\.com$[NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?)\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder/(.*?)/
RewriteRule ^(.*) /folder/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: this is just a url rewrite, it's NOT redefining the document root.  Document root should ALWAYS be set in the relevant apache configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

looks like this is what you need:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias *.localhost

    #the %1 is the asterisk value! No regexp supported!
    VirtualDocumentRoot /home/%1/project 
    VirtualScriptAlias  /home/%1/project

    <Directory /home/*/project/>
    #...
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score -3):

This can be done totally using htaccess .
You have to enable wildcard subdomain name *.domain.com and point it to domain.com

Then you can use the following types of rules :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+).domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*/) /%1/index.php [PT,L]
```

You can modify RewriteRule as files for subdomains are stored .

Comment: your code doesn't work
it still shows the parent index content

Comment: OK a little change to your code works Now

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www\.domain\.com$[NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?)\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !sites/(.*?)/
RewriteRule ^(.*) /sites/%1/index.php [L]

but i can not access subfolders of that directory, 4 example sub.domain.com/folder/ displays sub.domain.com/ contents